# How do I combine two integers in C#?

Tags: c#, floating-point, int

Let's say I have the following code:

```
int digit1 = 1;
int digit2 = 3;
```

and I need to combine the two integers, resulting in a floating-point number equal, in this case, to `13.0f`. This is probably easy, as I'm new to C# and learning it from a book, but how is it done?

Example:

```
int digit1 = 3;
int digit2 = 6;
float result = combine_integers (digit1, digit2);
// result = 36
```

NOTE:

I don't actually need a function. I just did that for the sake of the example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
float combine_integers (int digit1, int digit2)
{
    return 10*digit1 + digit2;
}
```

***Example***

```
combine_integers(1, 3) ==>
10 * 1 + 3 ==>
10 + 3 ==>
13
```

---

```
combine_integers(3, 6) ==>
10 * 3 + 6 ==>
30 + 6 ==>
36
```

Comment: Very clean and clever.

Comment: What happens though if digit2 is negative?

Comment: Negative values were not described in the original question, nor illustrated in the examples given.  Neither were multi-digit examples, such as `{12,34}`, therefore these are not covered by my solution.

Comment: Works but the intent is completely absent from the code, you have to interpret it rather than read it.

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues:  Thats what programming is.   I expect any student should be able to interpret the one line of code in my function, especially with the examples provided.

Comment: @abelenky you should verify your sources. Good programmers write code for humans, anyone can write code a machine can interpret, that's no feat.

Answer (score 0):

If your integers are single digits, then abelenky's answer above is going to do it quickest for you.  If they're not single digits, then you could do string.Format() as above, but there's also a couple of edge cases that aren't covered, such as negative values or both values being 0.

The string operations above could produce results such as "00", "5-1", or throw an error for not being able to parse the string result.  In the case of {5,-1}, you could end up with 49.

What I would do is cover my bases and assume that if you use a negative number, you want the absolute value.  This code also covers the base case of single digits, but gives you some flexibility so that combine_integers(12,34) returns 1234.0f.

```
    static float combine_integers (int digit1, int digit2)
    {
        int checker = Math.Abs(digit2);
        int result = Math.Abs(digit1);
        do
        {
            result *= 10;
            checker /= 10;
        } while(checker>0);
        result += Math.Abs(digit2);
        return (float)result;
    }
```

Comment: The amount of code here for a very simple problem is just pure overengineering. Let's keep it nice and short.

Answer (score -3):

```
private static float combine_integers(int a, int b)
{
    return float.Parse(a.ToString() + b.ToString());
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/M9Bpwt

Comment: Converting to strings just to combine and convert back to a float?  Massive Performance Slowdown!

Comment: This also provides a potential System.FormatException if b is a negative value.

Comment: Is this the most performant solution? Probably not. Do we have any context to what kind of performance is needed? Nope. So let's take a step back before we get all worked up about performance. You know what they say about early optimization.

Answer (score -3):

Try this code:

```
int digit1 = 3;
int digit2 = 6;
string concat = string.Format("{0}{1}", digit1, digit2);
float result = float.Parse(concat);
```

Comment: `string.Format` is SLOW!

Comment: If digit2 is a negative number, your code will throw a System.FormatException since "3-6" isn't a valid representation of a number.

Comment: Same here @abelenky. We don't know how much perf is needed. Assuming is just wrong. If it's so bad why would it be in the BCL? This code clearly conveys it's intent conversely yours doesn't at all.

Comment: `String.Format` is great for many string operations, which is why it is in the library.  However it is *not* appropriate for math operations.  It is a string function, not a math function.

Comment: It is a string function. We can look at this anyway we want to. Joining these numbers could even be an array operation if we wanted to. Let's be objective.